# My Android Studio doesn't have sync with Gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD83E.png)
This is my first time to ask question on stackoverflow.If I do something wrong please let me know!Thank you!
I am a beginner in app develope.And my question is on android studio.
This is my problem.I have search for the web for a long time and I got one answer was that need to find the「sync with grandle buttom」But I can not find the buttom on that specific place... Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZoK0.png)

Find a lot of website and I couldn't get it.
The exactly answer

Comment: That probably means you did not setup the project correctly or you are not in the correct working directory. Make sure you opened to project on the correct folder when opening it in android studio.

Comment: Oh.Thank you.I really found I setup something wrong.Thanks for helping